# How do I output "123 12 1" on separate lines with Java loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

can you hep me about my assignment?
it says that I have to create a program that the output is like this:

```
123
12
1
```

we gotta use loop statements

and I really can't think the answer.
please help me..

Comment: Looks like homework, why don't tag it this way.

Comment: Unless it's an assignment in internet usage, you'd be better off figuring this out yourself.

Comment: You should begin to read java 101 and more specifically the loop chapters!

Comment: I suggest you research/google  it and it will help you learn

Comment: The fact that you tagged this with "for-loop" says you know what loop construct to use. What you probably need help with is learning how to manipulate a string.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why I rolled back the edit, the original said _nothing_ about "given a non-negative integer" stuff. The assignment was a very simple "print out 123 12 1". I don't mind questions being edited to add clarity and fix minor errors but I'm not a big fan of changes that morph the basic nature of the question.

Comment: @gabuzo - Because [the homework tag is officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @Tony not in 2011 if I read correctly the meta question.

Answer (score 4):

Run an index, say we name it I, in a loop from N to 1, and inside the first loop run another index from 1 to I.

I think I told you enough.

---

***Clarification**: I see other people think you might have wanted to print the quotients when dividing a number by successive powers of 10. I find that situation not so probable. But if it's just a coincidence that your numbers have consecutive digits then please disregard my answer and take a look at the other posted here.*

Comment: Just in case: You may be under the wrong impression that `for` loops only go from 1 to N. Actually they are much more flexible than that. Ex.: `for(index=2*n;index>0 or otherStopCondition;index-=2)`

Answer (score 1):

Start with a string "123".

Loop from 0 to length of string - 1, in the loop print a slice of the string which starts at the beginning and ends at the loop index.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't tell us the big picture. Answering strictly to what you ask could lead to:

```
public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s :"123:12:1".split(":")) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }   
    }
}
```

But that's probably not what you want.

Edit: I know this is a stupid answer.

Comment: For the people that vote -1 I think gabuzo was ironic. So I'll + him :D

Comment: @Twister How is it useful? If you see the question is clearly phrased poorly, suggest a fix rather than a useless answer.

Comment: If you knew it was a stupid answer, you might have though twice about posting it. This ranks among the sociopaths that start their questions with "I know I should ask this here but ..." :-) No offence intened.

Comment: @marcog It is also obvious that he did not made a single search in google before posting the question. Nor reading his courses, nor reading a tutorial, nor...

Comment: @paxdiablo my answer is stupid but it was perfectly answering the question. I also think it is not much more stupid than any answer on this page: it prints what's asked and since we don't know the input everybody's playing Jeopardy. I don't think that I or anybody here has been offensive but yet no answer or comment from the question's author. It can be fun to solve homework as long as you have everything to solve it. BTW: no offense taken.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo code to get you started:

```
for limit = 3 to 1 inclusive:
    for number = 1 to limit inclusive:
        output number with no new line
    output new line
```

Your job is to translate that into Java (since it's classwork) and you can do that with the use of `for` loops along with `System.out.print/println` calls.

---

However, given this question was asked almost five years ago, I suspect you've probably had to hand something in by now so I have no qualms about now giving *actual* code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int limit = 3; limit > 0; limit--) {
            for (int number = 1; number <= limit; number++) {
                System.out.print(number);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that program is, as desired:

```
123
12
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two loops:

First you loop from 3 to 1. That will give you the three blocks.

Second in each iteration of your first loop you loop from 1 up to the value of your first variable while building the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int pow10 = 1; pow10 < n; pow10 *= 10)
    System.out.println(n / pow10);
```

Also a good case for a do-while:

```
do
    System.out.println(n);
while ((n /= 10) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 123;
for ( int i = a; i > 0; i = i/10 ) { System.out.println(i); }
```

Can't get much simpler than this when using a for loop.

Comment: I always love downvotes without one comment...

Comment: It's a common opinion amongst some here that code answers to homework question are not helpful, which is probably why the answer from @Alin is currently highest voted. That's most likely the reason for your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "123 12 1";
String[] somePartsOfString = string.split("\\ ");
for (int i = 0; i < somePartsOfString.length; i++){
   System.out.println(somePartsOfString[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An obscure solution which might amuse... ;)

```
Random r = new Random(292012);
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
    int n=r.nextnt(4);
    System.out.print(n<1?"\n":""+n);
}
```